# SQL select unique elements and compare them on two periods

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Lets say we have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I want to be able to see how many URL records are there during period1 and period2.

where period 1 is "date > '2016-01-01' and date < '2017-01-01' "

and period 2 is "date > '2014-01-1' and date < '2015-01-01' "

Here is what visualization of my expectations :

[image]

I can easily do this with one single period using following query:

```
SELECT URL, COUNT(URL) as Period1 
FROM table WHERE  date < '2017-01-01' 
AND  date > '2016-01-01' GROUP BY URL
```

But how do I add second column with Period2?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Sorry if I explained myself incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT  
  URL AS uri,
  COUNTIF(date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') AS Period1,
  COUNTIF(date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31') AS Period2
FROM `LogFilesv2_Dataset.DE_Visits` 
GROUP BY URL
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the dates in below query and it will count the hits per period

```
SELECT  [URL]
,SUM(CASE WHEN (date >= '12/22/2015' And date <='12/23/2015') THEN 1 Else  0 END)
,SUM(CASE WHEN (date > '12/30/2015' And date  < '12/31/2015') THEN 1 Else  0 END)
FROM LogFilesv2_Dataset.DE_Visits 
Group by URL
```

Comment: i am really curious - why to vote up wrong answer(s)!? there are so many such cases recently! :o(

Comment: My, bad, is actually SUM, not Count

Comment: this answer(edited version) also does return correct output, as far as I see. thank you very much, Rafael, I really appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which database you are using. But for Oracle database you can try using scalar sub-queries like this.

```
select url,(select count(*) from test where url=t.url and date_col <= sysdate and date_col  > sysdate-20) period1,(select count(*) from test where url=t.url and date_col <= sysdate and date_col  > sysdate-40) period2
```

from test t group by url;

You can replace date range appropriately in the query above.

It is always helpful to provide SQL scripts to create the table and populate the data.